# Search all Sites on Multisite

Tags: search, multi-site

I have a multisite setup and and a search bar at the top of each site. Currently it just searches within that site:

```
{% set theSite = craft.app.request.getSegment(1) %}
{% paginate craft.entries.search(search).site(theSite).orderBy('score').limit(9) as pageInfo, pageEntries %}
```

The first segment defines the site.
I need to expand the searches to include all entries in all sites. Is this possible? I tried variations of getAllSites and just .site but of course those didn't work.

If its not possible to search all sites at once I may look at running each search and adding all of the results together.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Entries Query only allows you to search one site at a time.  Here is the documentation for the [Site Object](https://docs.craftcms.com/v3/dev/element-queries/entry-queries.html#site) or [Site Id](https://docs.craftcms.com/v3/dev/element-queries/entry-queries.html#siteid) query params.

You can get each site by:

```
{% set sites = craft.app.sites.allSites %}
{% for site in sites %}
    …        
{% endfor %}
```

Answer (score 2):

Currently, you unfortunately can't query all sites within your entires, you will have to separate your results out with a for-loop by site, as @aran did above.

Craft 3.2 will thankfully fix this by allowing you to pass sites to an array or query sites('*') to return entries from all your sites:

https://github.com/craftcms/cms/commit/d01702278bd84b84392e11da72aa4d0b6f4f0943

Comment: You can now use `craft.entries().section('news').site('*')` https://github.com/craftcms/cms/issues/2854#issuecomment-471371467